# Is this implementation correct for singleton?

Tags: java, singleton

I want to implement a singleton class, would you tell me: my implementation is correct? if not, please tell me why. 
thanks

```
public class Singleton {
    private String str ;
    private final static Singleton ss = new Singleton();
    private Singleton(){

    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        return ss;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Enum for Singleton.

Comment: This implementation is not fully correct.

Comment: IMHO this question is too broad. Too many factors could be evaluated in order to provide a "correct" answer and generate a lot of different opinions: thread safety, performance, code readability, etc. If you define the scope of correctness.... that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is fine and is thread safe.
The singleton instantiation performed in a static field this is :

```
private final static Singleton ss = new Singleton();
```

prevents any race condition as it is executed before that the object be accessible and the remaining of the code guarantees also that only one instance of the class is created, particularly because this statement is the single time where the constructor is invoked and the constructor is private too.

Note that this is an eager instantiation. You could also use a lazy way with a static holder class but it is really noise because the overhead is almost null.

Answer (score 1):

The way I implement a singleton is like so:

```
public class Singleton {
  private static Singleton _instance;

  private Singleton() {
  }

  public static Singleton getInstance() {
      if (_instance == null) {
         _instance = new Singleton();
      }
      return _instance;
  }
```

Comment: This is not thread-safe. Enums are the simplest way to get thread-safe and correct singleton in Java.

Comment: True.  But I was working under the assumption OP wasn't using multithreading since it wasn't mentioned.  Can modify the answer as needed if that's the case.

Answer (score -2):

public class Singleton  {

```
private Singleton () {
}

 public static Singleton() {
    return new Singleton();
 }
```

}

Comment: Returning a different instance each time is the exact opposite of a _singleton_.

Comment: constructor cant not be static method